# ¿Cómo rellenar array o arraylist con colores rgb aleatorios para usarlos más adelante?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, arraylist, bucles

Tengo este método:

```
public int coloresAleatorio(int i) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

    return color;
}
```

También definí un arraylist:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> coloresArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {                  
      coloresArray.add(color);    

} //END FOR
```

Necesito meterlos en el arraylist para usarlos después en el orden en el que se generan, por ejemplo:

```
botonReset.setBackgroundColor(coloresArray[1]);
```

Comment: Por qué necesitas un argumento `i` en tu función `coloresAleatorio`? No lo estás usando. También me he fijado en que aunque coloresArray es una lista, estás accediendo a un elemento con `[i]` - deberías usar `.get(i)` en su lugar.

Comment: en lugar de  coloresArray.add(colorAleatorio()); usa  coloresArray.add(coloresAleatorio(i));    para crear el color aleatorio que se agregaría al array coloresArray. @Paco

Comment: Paco, me parece que también estas confundiendo Array y ArrayList, la forma de agregar y obtener los elementos se realiza de diferente forma.

Answer (score 0):

Con tu código actual parece que no estás usando la función que tú mismo has definido.

No hace falta pasar un argumento a la función que genera el color, ya que no lo estás usando:

```
public int colorAleatorio() {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

    return color;
}
```

Una vez definida esta función, es cuestión de usarla para llenar tu lista:

```
// El modificador "public" no puede usarse dentro de un método
ArrayList<Integer> colores = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {                  
      coloresArray.add(colorAleatorio());
}
```

El acceso a elementos al índice `i` en una `List` se hace con `.get(i)`, no `[i]`. Por tanto:

```
botonReset.setBackgroundColor(colores.get(i));
```

Hay dos cosas más que pueden ser mejoradas:

- `ArrayList` debe aparecer a la derecha de la expresión, pero puedes definir el tipo de la variable `colores` como `List`. En eso consiste la estructura object-oriented al fin y al cabo - cuanto mas genérico el tipo, en más sitios se puede usar.
- `ThreadLocalRandom` se suele preferir a `Random` y genera una fuente pseudorándom mucho más fuerte.

Answer (score 0):

Tu método es correcto, obtiene un valor aleatorio entero de un color:

```
public int coloresAleatorio(int i) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

    return color;
}
```

lo comprobe realizando una conversión a Hexadecimal del mismo:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {
     int intColor = coloresAleatorio(i);
     Log.w(TAG, "Color: "  + intColor);
     String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
     Log.w(TAG, "hexColor: "  + hexColor);
 }
```

**El problema es debido a que no estas llamando el método para crear el color aleatorio y agregarlo al ArrayList `coloresArray`**:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> coloresArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {       
      //coloresArray.add(colorAleatorio()); //INCORRECTO.          
      coloresArray.add(coloresAleatorio(i));    
}
```

**ahora para obtener los valores almacenados en el `ArrayList` esta es la forma correcta, mediante el método `get()`** :

```
//botonReset.setBackgroundColor(coloresArray[1]); // INCORRECTO.
botonReset.setBackgroundColor(coloresArray.get(1));
```